# Link Function Help Needed!

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, link-function

Help needed with link functions!
I'm attempting to do some linear models examining how fork lenghts of fish are dependent upon sex (0 or 1), hatchery mark (0 or 1) and age (continuous). When I try a standard model, some or all assumptions fail. I'm thinking a link function would be helpful, but wondering if someone could lead me on right path for which would make most sense.

Comment: This may be helpful: [Von Bertalanffy Growth Models](http://derekogle.com/fishR/examples/oldFishRVignettes/VonBertalanffy.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Fork length will be necessarily positive, and you probably want to start with a conditional distribution that will make some sense first before trying to choose your link. (I'd suggest looking at a Gamma GLM perhaps, especially since I'd expect the spread to be larger when the mean is larger. However, the Gaussian may not be unreasonable if spread is pretty constant with the ages you look at)

Given a reasonable conditional distribution for length, the binary variables won't matter as far as the form of the link function, so it's only age that you would worry about the form of the link function for.

If I understand rightly, typically fish length seems to grow roughly linearly at young ages before slowing down (in some cases it seems to level off completely, in other species it seems to settle to a slow roughly linear increase, and in others it might even come back down a bit). Whichever kind of thing you might be dealing with, I'm pretty sure this won't leave you with a linear relationship with age for *any* common choice of link function.

You may need to consider something like (i) a curvilinear parametric model (e.g. a model with several different age-terms that between them can model the relationship with age you expect to see), (ii) a nonparametric regression (such as a natural cubic spline model perhaps, especially if it's the linear changing to slower-linear case) or (iii) a nonlinear regression/nonlinear GLM (especially if there's some well-known model for the shape of that progression*)

* I've seen for example, the von Bertalanffy type growth function used in some situaitons -- $E(L) = L_\infty [1 - e^{ -K (t - t_0)}]$; that may not suit your particular application (many other curves may be used or may be better) but it gives a sense of the kind of thing that might be used for that nonlinear option. If used with a non-linear link function you'd have the link function modifying some functional relationship with age ($t$) like that one (yielding a different function).